# lapply to convert list of dataframes to xts objects - subscript out of bounds error

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, xts

I have a list of 31 data frames (split_data_V3.0) that I am trying to convert to xts object using lapply. The code gets executed but when I try to open the elements from the new lists (split_data_V3.0_zoo, split_data_V3.0_xts) I get the error message "Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds". Could someone help with this ?

```
grouping <- data_V3.0_csv$Symbol
split_data_V3.0 <- split(data_V3.0_csv, grouping)

split_data_V3.0_zoo <- lapply(split_data_V3.0, function (x) read.zoo(x, index.column = c("X")))
split_data_V3.0_xts <- lapply(split_data_V3.0_zoo, function(x) as.xts(x))
```

Error message:

```
 split_data_V3.0_zoo <- lapply(split_data_V3.0, function (x) read.zoo(x, index.column = c("X")))
> split_data_V3.0_xts <- lapply(split_data_V3.0_zoo, function(x) as.xts(x))
> View(split_data_V3.0_zoo)
> View(split_data_V3.0_xts)
Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: I also tried with this, but I get the same:                                    ```indices_df_transform <- function(symbol){
  symbol_zoo <- read.zoo(symbol, index.column = c("X"))
  as.xts(symbol_zoo)
}

split_data_V3.0_xts <- lapply(split_data_V3.0, indices_df_transform)```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).